# Entity Framework Database First - addition of self-referencing foreign key deletes HashSet after Scaffold-DBContext command execution

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-database-first

I am using Entity Framework Core, C#, to create an .NETCoreApp1.1 service. I have two tables, `Organizations` and `Assets` with a one-many relationship `Organizations.Id` -> `Assets.OrganizationId`.

The Scaffold-DbContext command creates an `Organizations` class with `public member Assets = new HashSet<Assets>` and an `ICollection<Assets> Assets`.

```
public Organizations()
{
    Assets = new HashSet<Assets>();
    Components = new HashSet<Components>();

}

(properties)

public virtual ICollection<Assets> Assets { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Components> Components { get; set; }
```

After adding a self-referencing foreign key to the `Organizations` table where parent is `Organizations.Id` and child is `Organizations.ParentId`, execution of the Scaffold-DbContext command eliminates the `Assets HashSet` and the `ICollection<Assets>` which causes a build error.

Can anyone help with this issue? I'm new to database first EF and cannot determine why this error is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my goodness, the scaffolding was creating another object and that new object name needed to be updated in the controller, the error had nothing at all to do with the foreign keys.